# JavaFX Treeview expand Arrow move to the right

Tags: css, javafx, treeview, css-position, expand

So i search everywhere for this and couldn't find it.

I'm using a treeview and i'm trying to move the expand arrow to the right.

[This is what i have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K9Lx.png)

[This is what im aiming for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtMVO.png)

The thing im aiming for has a - on the right, i want my arrow in the same position

Im currently using css

```
.tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow  {
-fx-background-color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

so add a `float:right;` or use `margin-left:80%`
If that wont work, maybe can u copy html structure? That will be helpfull

Comment: No it doesn't work like that, i got it to kinda work when i inverted the table and then inverted the text however it looks cluncky